# Sequel Model is not mapping all columns by default

Tags: ruby, sequel

Sequel Model is not mapping all columns by default.

I'm using: 
Sequel version 4.24.0
Ruby version 1.9.3p194
Windows Server 2008 Enterprise
SQLServer 2008 R2 Enterprise

Below is a brief script that shows the problem:

```
require "sequel"

DB = Sequel.ado(:conn_string=>CONNECTION_STRING)

print "Loading LnProfile... "
class LnProfile < Sequel::Model(:lnprofile)
#  attr_accessor :crawl_start_time
end
puts "Done!"

id = "808d8421-6c05-471e-addc-6165de044ad3"

# crawl_start_time field shouldn't be empty
p1 = LnProfile.where(:id=>id).first  
puts ".id:#{p1.id.to_s}:." # => .id:808d8421-6c05-471e-addc-6165de044ad3:.
puts ".crawl_start_time:#{p1.crawl_start_time.to_s}:." # => .crawl_start_time::.

# same record, different data
p2 = LnProfile.select_all.select_append(:crawl_start_time).where(:id=>id).first  
puts ".id:#{p2.id.to_s}:."  # => .id:808d8421-6c05-471e-addc-6165de044ad3:.
puts ".crawl_start_time:#{p2.crawl_start_time.to_s}:." # => .crawl_start_time:2016-01-10 12:02:29 -0300:.
```

Below is the output of the script above:

```
Loading LnProfile... Done!
.id:{808D8421-6C05-471E-ADDC-6165DE044AD3}:.
.crawl_start_time::.
.id:{808D8421-6C05-471E-ADDC-6165DE044AD3}:.
.crawl_start_time:2016-01-10 12:02:29 -0300:.
```

Please advice. This issue is dirtying the database when the code loads an object and saves it again few lines above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm rewriting the whole code, adding the methods "select_all.select_append(...)" to all the objects loading sentences, in order to ensure that all critical fields will be loaded... but I will like a more stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tinytds adapter, it is much more robust than the ado adapter.

Comment: Maybe. But I don't think it can be an ADO's bug. It's more like a compatibility problem between Sequel and ADO. Can I expect a fix patch for Sequel for this issue?